# Ember-simple-auth get user object nested promise

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, promise

I'm trying to get the 'session.current_user' object accessible in all routes and controllers. It should be accessible as a promise, so I can prefilter models from the controllers. But I can't seem to get the promise chain working correctly.

I have this in the authentication initializer of ember-simple-auth

```
Ember.Application.initializer
  name: 'authentication',
  initialize: (container, application) ->
    Ember.SimpleAuth.Authenticators.OAuth2.reopen
      serverTokenEndpoint: '/oauth/token'

    Ember.SimpleAuth.Session.reopen
      +computed
      current_user: ->
        Ember.run ->
          Ember.$.get('/api/v1/credentials/me').then (response) ->
            container.lookup('store:main').find('user', response.user.id)
```

And this in the application controller:

```
class App.ApplicationController extends Ember.Controller
  +computed session.current_user
  current_user_gravatar_url: ->
    @get('session.current_user').then (current_user) ->
      # but I get this here
      Em.inspect(current_user)
      # => "<DS.PromiseObject:ember656>"
      # 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + md5(current_user.get('email'))
```

The request to users model comes AFTER the application controller actions.

```
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/3".
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is the nesting too deep or should I somehow split the 'current_user' computed property into separate dependent computed properties>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example in the Ember.SimpleAuth repo that illustrates how to do that: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/4-authenticated-account.html

Comment: I am not sure if that is the idiomatic way of accessing user credentials in oauth.

Comment: That example is not OAuth but a customization of the "Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant Type". If you want to use the grant type as it is defined in the spec you could simple get the current user from e.g. /users/me after authentication.

Comment: Thats what I tried to do here. Thanks anyways - I will use your solution of modifying the /oauth/token instead

Comment: I followed the example and now my template renders my session.user as a <DS.PromiseObject>. What am I doing wrong?